# How to create add button with ModelChoiceField in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

`IP` and `System` have a to one relationship.

I've created custom form

```
class SystemAdminForm(ModelForm):
    address = ModelChoiceField(IP.objects.filter(system=None))

class Meta:
    model = System
```

And that's how I'm using it now.

```
class SystemAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = SystemAdminForm
```

I want two things:

`IP` field should not be shown and address field to have + button.

How can I do that?

[image]

```
class IPAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'ip']

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True

class SystemAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = SystemAdminForm

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True

admin.site.register(System, SystemAdmin)
admin.site.register(IP, IPAdmin)
```

Comment: IP is already a `ModelChoiceField`, what is the problem you have with it?

Comment: IP.objects.filter(system=None)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the solution to remove ip field:

```
class Meta:
    model = System
    exclude ＝ ["ip"]
```

and to have the + button you need to override this function in AddressAdmin

```
class AddressAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True
admin.site.register(Adress, AddressAdmin)
```

Comment: you means `exclude ＝ ( "ip" )`?

Comment: ["ip"] sorry, my mistake。

Comment: just register the address model in the admin to get the plus sign

Comment: The first suggestion works, thank you.
But as for the second - neither your answer suggestion nor the comments suggestion is working.

Comment: what is address model? I think the has_add_permission should be put in the address admin model. I have modified my answer.

Comment: could you show me your address model and addressAdmin model?